# Coluring the scatterplot in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have two vectors

```
 A=rnorm(500)
 B=rnorm(500)
```

And wanted to create a scatterplot and used

```
   Plot(A,B,cex=0.5,col="grey") ### this creates the base scatterplot
```

Now, I have two more conditions wherein I have three vectors which is a subset of the original ones:

```
 C<-subset[A,select=c(1:10,20:30,60:75,90,100) ### to be coloured in blue
 D<-subset[A,select=c(25:60)] ### to be coloured in blue
 E<-subset[B,select=c(100:150,120:125)] ### to be colured in red.
```

How should I modify the scatterplot to change the color for these vectors C,D,E alone from the original grey colour?? The concept is similar to this:

[image: XY Scatterplot]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by changing the colour of the vectors, C, D, E? If you mean change the colours in the scatterplot, you need to input two vectors of same length. Also, the code you provide is not valid R code.

Comment: @ialm : Yes, the solution is right. Thanks. I would like to replace the gray points with the coloured ones based on the subset vectors which stands for each condition.

Comment: Glad it worked. Also, note that there is some overlap in the indices specified by `C` and `D`, so the duplicated indices will be coloured by which ever call comes last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I interpreted your question:

"Plot the subset of points indicated by the indices `C`, `D`, `E` in the question with different colours".

```
A <- rnorm(500)
B <- rnorm(500)

## Set the indices, as written in question
Ci <- c(1:10,20:30,60:75,90,100) ### to be coloured in blue
Di <- c(25:60)                   ### to be coloured in blue
Ei <- c(100:150,120:125)         ### to be coloured in red.

## Plot the original scatterplot, then plot over the points of interest with colour
## Use the "points" function from base graphics to plot points on existing plot
## Grab the relevant points from vectors A and B by accessing them at indices 
## Ci, Di, Ei using `[]`
plot(A, B, cex=0.5, col="grey")
points(A[Ci], B[Ci], cex=0.5, col="blue")
points(A[Di], B[Di], cex=0.5, col="blue")
points(A[Ei], B[Ei], cex=0.5, col="red")
```